# Mobile questions sorted by newest bug

Tags: bug, mobile-web, active

If you use the mobile mode, then sort questions by *newest*, the usernames displayed won't be the ones of the author, they will be the one who made the last activity (just like when we sort by *active* in the normal mode).

[image]

I believe this is a bug, it wouldn't make much sense why it behaves different from the non-mobile mode.

Note: I didn't check with other kind of sorting, but maybe it happens with others too.

Comment: Yikes, you should charge your iPod. ;)

Comment: @Skliwz discussion?! If it's by design, it's totally fair to tag as such. But bug report can hardly be a discussion...

Comment: The list of favorites on one’s profile page also lists the name of the editor rather than of the OP, no matter which sorting option.